# Error running hadoop application in Eclipse on Windows

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I'm trying to set up an Eclipse environment for developing and debugging hadoop. I'm following Tom White's Definitive Hadoop 3rd ed. What I would like to do is get the MaxTemperature app working locally on my Windows within Eclipse before moving it to my Hortonworks sandbox VM. The comment on page 158 about using the local job runner seems to be what I want. I don't want to set up a full hadoop implementation on Windows. I'm hoping with the right config params I can convince it to run as a java application inside Eclipse.

Windows: 7
Eclipse: Luna
Hadoop: 2.4.0
JDK: 7

When I set the Run configuration for MaxTemperatureDriver (Source code on page 157) to

```
  inputfile outputdir foo (deliberate bogus 3rd parameter)
```

I get the usage message so I know I'm running my program with those params.

If I remove the bogus third param I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1251)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at mark.MaxTemperatureDriver.run(MaxTemperatureDriver.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at mark.MaxTemperatureDriver.main(MaxTemperatureDriver.java:56)
```

I've tried inserting -conf  but it seems to be ignored. There is no error message if I specify a nonexistent path.
I've tried inserting `-fs file:/// -jt local`, but it makes no difference
I've tried inserting `-D mapreduce.framework.name=local`
I've tried specifying the input and output with the file: format

Note. I'm not asking about how to configure eclipse to connect to a remote Hadoop installation. I want the application to run within eclipse.

Is this possible? Any ideas?

Additional info:
I turned on debugging. I saw:

```
582 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider
583 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Cannot pick org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider - returned null protocol
```

I'm wondering not why YarnClientProtocolProvider failed, but why it didn't try LocalClientProtocolProvider.

New info:
It seems that this is an issue with Hadoop 2.4.0. I recreated my environment with Hadoop 1.2.1, followed the instructions in

http://gerrymcnicol.com/index.php/2014/01/02/hadoop-and-cassandra-part-4-writing-your-first-mapreduce-job/

added the Windows hack from

http://bigdatanerd.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/mapreduce-running-mapreduce-in-windows-file-system-debug-mapreduce-in-eclipse

and it all started working.

Comment: check whether all the 5 servers are running or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Following blog will be useful.
[Running mapreduce in Windows filesystem](http://bigdatanerd.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/mapreduce-running-mapreduce-in-windows-file-system-debug-mapreduce-in-eclipse/#respond)